# Can webdriverio tests be executed on Unix

Tags: javascript, unix, automated-tests, webdriver-io

How can we execute webdriverio Tests on Unix platform. Would the below command work ?

```
npx wdio run ./wdio.conf.js
```

Answer (score 0):

WebdriverIO is basically a package that resides in NPM [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriverio). That means you need to follow [system requirements](https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted/#system-requirements) for this package, which means installing a certain version of Node.js. And that could run on multiple OS.